# Counting Cunningham chains

Tags: code-golf, primes

Prime numbers have always fascinated people. 2300 years ago Euclid wrote in his "Elements"

> A prime number is that which is measured by a unit alone.

which means that a prime is only divisible by `1` (or by itself).

People have always looked for relations between prime numbers, and have come up with some pretty weird (as in "interesting") stuff.

For example a **Sophie Germain prime** is a prime `p` for which `2*p+1` is also prime.

A **safe prime** is a prime `p` for which `(p-1)/2` is also prime, which is exactly the backwards condition of a Sophie Germain prime.

These are related to what we are looking for in this challenge.

A **[Cunningham chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain) of type I** is a series of primes, where every element except the last one is a **Sophie Germain prime**, and every element except the first one is a **safe prime**. The number of elements in this *chain* is called it's **length**.

This means that we start with a prime `p` and calculate `q=2*p+1`. If `q` is prime too, we have a Cunnigham chain of type **I** of length 2. Then we test `2*q+1` and so on, until the next generated number is composite.

Cunningham chains of type **II** are constructed following almost the same principle, the only difference being that we check `2*p-1` at each stage.

Cunningham chains can have a *length of 1*, which means that neither 2*p+1 nor 2*p-1 are prime. **We're not interested in these**.

### Some examples of Cunningham chains

`2` starts a chain of type **I** of length 5.

`2, 5, 11, 23, 47`

The next constructed number would be `95` which isn't prime.
This also tells us, that `5`, `11`, `23` and `47` don't start any chain of type **I**, because it would have preceeding elements.

`2` also starts a chain of type **II** of length 3.

`2, 3, 5`

Next would be `9`, which isn't prime.

Let's try `11` for type **II** (we excluded it from *type I* earlier).
Well, `21` would be next, which isn't prime, so we would have length 1 for that "chain", which we don't count in this challenge.

### Challenge

> Write a program or function that, given a number `n` as input, writes/returns the starting number of the **nth** Cunningham chain of **type I or II** of **at least length 2**, followed by a space, followed by the type of chain it starts (**I** or **II**), followed by a colon, followed by the length of that type of chain.
>   In case a prime starts both types of chains (type I *and* type II) the chain of type I is counted first.
>
> Example: `2 I:5`

Bear in mind, that `n` might be part of a previously started chain of any type, in which case it shouldn't be considered a *starting number* of a chain of that type.

### Let's look into how this begins

We start with `2`. Since it is the first prime at all we can be sure that there is no chain starting with a lower prime that contains `2`.
The next number in a chain of type I would be `2*2+1 == 5`. `5` is prime, so we have a chain of at least length 2 already.
We count that as the first chain.
What about type II?
Next number would be `2*2-1 == 3`. `3` is prime, so a chain of at least length 2 for type II too.
We count that as the second chain. And we're done for `2`.

Next prime is `3`. Here we should check if it is in a chain that a lower prime started.
Check for type I: `(3-1)/2 == 1`. `1` isn't prime, so 3 could be a starting point for a chain of type I.
Let's check that. Next would be `3*2+1 == 7`. `7` is prime, so we have a chain of type I of at least length 2. We count that as the third chain.
Now we check if `3` appears in a type II chain that a lower prime started.
`(3+1)/2 == 2`. `2` is prime, so 3 can't be considered as a *starting number* for a chain of type II. So this is not counted, even if the next number after `3` in this chain, which would be `5`, is prime.
(Of course we already knew that, and you can and should of course think about your own method how to do these checks.)

And so we check on for `5`, `7`, `11` and so on, counting until we find the nth Cunningham chain of at least length 2.

Then (or maybe some time earlier `;)` ) we need to determine the complete length of the chain we found and print the result in the previously mentioned format.

By the way: in my tests I haven't found any prime besides `2` that started both types of chains with a length greater than `1`.

### Input/Output examples

> #### Input
>
> `1`
>
> #### Output
>
> `2 I:5`

> #### Input
>
> `10`
>
> #### Output
>
> `79 II:3`

> #### Input
>
> `99`
>
> #### Output
>
> `2129 I:2`

#### The outputs for the inputs 1..20

```
2 I:5
2 II:3
3 I:2
7 II:2
19 II:3
29 I:2
31 II:2
41 I:3
53 I:2
79 II:3
89 I:6
97 II:2
113 I:2
131 I:2
139 II:2
173 I:2
191 I:2
199 II:2
211 II:2
229 II:2
```

A list of the first 5000 outputs can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/m22P9XMR).

This is code golf. Arbitrary whitespace is allowed in the output, but the type and numbers should be seperated by a single space and a colon as seen in the examples. Using any loopholes is not allowed, especially getting the results from the web is **not** allowed.

Good luck `:)`

Comment: Forgot to mention in the sandbox: it's easy to prove that `2` and `3` are the only primes `p` for which both `2p-1` and `2p+1` are primes, so `2` is the only prime which *starts* non-trivial Cunningham chains of both types.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help `:)`

Comment: (Converted comment from answer.) There *aren't* any primes other than `2` with a dual chain length greater than 1. [Here is a proof by elimination.](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qpJV3L4a)

Comment: Well thanks for pointing that out in such detail again. Did you just want to remark that or do you think I should change the challenge somehow because of this?

Comment: Only a remark. I don't think it changes the challenge in any case, only potentially helpful for golfing: when one chain is found, the other doesn't need to be checked.

Comment: A prime is divisible by TWO whole numbers: 1 and itself.

Comment: I guess Euclid took it for granted that a number is divisible by itself. `;)` Or can be measured by itself.

Comment: [Related OEIS](http://oeis.org/A111145)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>236</s> 208 bytes

Saved 28 bytes:

```
p=(n,i=n)=>n%--i?p(n,i):i==1;f=n=>{for(k=2,c=0;c<n;k++){p(k)&&!p((k-1)/2)&&p(2*k+1)&&(c++,l=1,r='');p(k)&&c-n&&!p((k+1)/2)&&p(2*k-1)&&(c++,l=-1,r='I');};alert(--k+` I${r}:`+eval(`for(j=1;p(k=2*k+l);j++);j`))}
```

Saved 9 bytes on `p` function with: `p=(n,i=n)=>n%--i?p(n,i):i==1`
The `t` function was replaced by the `eval(...)` statement directly in the `f` function.

---

**Previous solution:**

```
p=n=>{for(i=n;n%--i&&i;);return 1==i};t=(n,m)=>{for(j=1;p(n=2*n+m);j++);return j};f=n=>{for(k=2,c=0;c<n;k++){p(k)&&!p((k-1)/2)&&p(2*k+1)&&(c++,l=1,r='');p(k)&&c-n&&!p((k+1)/2)&&p(2*k-1)&&(c++,l=-1,r='I');};alert(--k+` I${r}:${t(k,l)}`)}
```

Example: `f(6)`

Output: `29 I:2`

**Explanation**
I'm using 3 functions

**1** *p*: to know if *n* is prime :
`p=n=>{for(i=n;n%--i&&i;);return 1==i}`

**2** *t*: to know the length of the Cunningham chain starting with *n* of type I or II depending on the *m* parameter which will be 1 or -1 :
`t=(n,m)=>{for(j=1;p(n=2*n+m);j++);return j}`

**3** *f*: counts the chains (*for loop*) then display the result

```
f=n=>{for(k=2,c=0;c<n;k++){p(k)&&!p((k-1)/2)&&p(2*k+1)&&(c++,l=1,r='');p(k)&&c-n&&!p((k+1)/2)&&p(2*k-1)&&(c++,l=-1,r='I');};alert(--k+` I${r}:${t(k,l)}`)}
```

*for loop*: for each number the Cunningham chain (I then II if needed) is valid if

- the number is prime
- the predecessor is not prime
- the successor is prime

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 182 bytes

```
Union[Flatten[DeleteCases[Table[c@x_:=Module[{t=0,p=Prime@k},If[PrimeQ[(p-x)/2],1,While[PrimeQ@p,p=2p+x;t++];t]];{Prime@k,If[#==1,"I","II"],c@#},{k,7!}],{a_,b_,1}]&/@{1,-1},1]][[#]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxRS8MwFIX/Sk2gKL2jS30YrAQCG0IfBBXFh8ulZDV2ZW1WXIRCyG@Pmfpw4DuHc86k3dFM2g2djr18@hqsQw4ZyxhkvEqwZcDvKVcqvtnhbPFh1M4Zi3szGmd2@mIu@KoPo8FOLe1WPp4/vpPxTq5hvh5ORp0CNJ/4y894O6@Wu7IiEPB@HFL1L1dzqldzsdSuKKh2RLX/X1/HXEoBrGFJDSPoFA/gT7C5CQRet3BoQQTKS@UFrEQAQYTIifLYl@pF296oah3jDw)

[image]